# How to copy the data saved to local storage using Copy Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have got a table with **textarea** where i am saving the data to **local storage**.I tried using the below code to copy the table and its content.But it is not copying the data  saved to local storage.only the table is being copied.
I am new to local storage concept.

```
       <table id ="tableId" >
         <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1  </th>
            <th>Heading 2 </th>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td><textarea class="saveTxt"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="saveTxt"></textarea></td>
        </tr> 


    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Copy table" onclick="selectElementContents(document.getElementById('tableId') );">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script>

            jQuery(document).ready (function () {

               saveDataToLocal();

               });


        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* copy table content */
    function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
            document.execCommand("copy");

        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
            range.execCommand("Copy");
        }
    }

function saveDataToLocal() {
  var text = document.querySelectorAll('.saveTxt');
   /* code to save data to local storage*/

}

        </script>
```

Can i get some suggestions on it?Thank You!

Comment: `localStorage` is a built-in method in JS. Try `localStorage.setItem("YOU_TEXT_KEY", JSON.stringify(text))`

Answer (score 0):

This is my demo. Hope this helps

```
<table id ="tableId" >
     <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1  </th>
        <th>Heading 2 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><textarea class="saveTxt">abc</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="saveTxt">xyz</textarea></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

copy the table and its content

```
var table_copy = $('#tableId').html();
localStorage.setItem('table',table_copy);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("table"));
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/0psuqxy1/4/